# Flutter BottomNavigationBar Colors

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to change the selected color of a BottomNavigation icon but all I seem to be achieving is changing the text colours. Please assist:

Currently the text color changes to yellow when selected but the icon stays white, I want it to be yellow too and I have tried setting the icon color of the inactive icons to grey like the caption but it's not budging.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
new Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: Colors.black,
          splashColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
            unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.green,
          primaryColor: Colors.red,
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
        ),
        child: new BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, color: Colors.white,),
                title: new Text("Services"),
            ),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Theme(
                  data: new ThemeData(

                  ),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.white,)),
                title: new Text("Appointment")
            ),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.face, color: Colors.white,),
                title: new Text("Profile")
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: index,
          onTap: (int i){setState((){index = i;});},
          fixedColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 18):

Don't declare the color of icon inside `BottomNavigationBarItem`.
You should declare it inside `BottomNavigationBar` as `unselectedItemColor` and `selectedItemColor`.

```dart
   bottomNavigationBar:
    BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.green,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.yellow,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

By doing so, your code will work.

Answer (score 15):

You've explicitly set `color: Colors.white` for each of the icons, so they will be white until you set them otherwise.

You have a couple of options:

1. Set your BottomNavigationBar's type to `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed` and set `fixedColor: Colors.orange` or whatever color you want. Note that you'll have to remove your `color: Colors.white` or they will still be white.
2. You could test for the right index being set and then decide which color to set the icon to directly, i.e. `color = index == 0 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor` for the first item, `index==1` for the second, and `item==2` for the third.
3. A slight alternative would be to set an IconTheme with color=unselectedColor around the entire BottomNavigationBar, then only set the selected item with `color = index == 0 ? selectedColor : null`.

I'd recommend reading the [BottomNavigationBar documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html), particularly the part about fixed vs shifting, as it describes the answer to the exact problem you're having.

Note that `BottomNavigatorBar` is no longer recommended for new code as it has been replaced with the more flexible `NavigationBar`.

Comment: Dead link. Here's the updated one: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Also, it's worth pointing out that you may want to migrate to NavigationBar. It gives you more control of the items since it takes any Widget instead of only BottomNavigationBarItem.

Answer (score 2):

This how you could set the color of the icon:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.yellow),
              unselectedIconTheme:  IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
```

Answer (score 0):

fixedColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
just remove this line, and it's worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).