# BottomNavigationBar color incorrectly change

Tags: flutter

I've a bottomnavigation bar that has a color. When I clicked on the last button, the color change to white ...

The last button show some card i can swipe.
For that i use the code here : https://github.com/devefy/Flutter-Story-App-UI

i've tried to change return container() whith something else, but nothing was heplful.

here is my code

```dart
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (edifice != null) _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.unEdifice.vocable),
        backgroundColor: color_edifices,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: edifice == null
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : _selectedIndex == 5
                ? SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CardScrollWidget(currentPage),
                            Positioned.fill(
                              child: PageView.builder(
                                itemCount: edifice.commentaires.length,
                                controller: controller,
                                reverse: true,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Container(
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                : _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: color_edifices,
            icon: Icon(GaeoIcons.church, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text('Edifice', style: buttonTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(GaeoIcons.location_on, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text('Adresses', style: buttonTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(GaeoIcons.group, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text('Responsables', style: buttonTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(GaeoIcons.truck, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text('Distributions', style: buttonTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(GaeoIcons.group, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text('Contacts', style: buttonTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(GaeoIcons.comment, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text('Commentaires', style: buttonTextStyle),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

You can see what i mean with the pictures included

Thanks for your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Above the @override   void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (edifice != null) _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  },   i've changed the code in the question to reflect its exact position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to simulate your case with Story App UI
please try to 
1. add BottomNavigationBar 's backgroundColor 
2. test with BottomNavigationBarType.fixed and fixedColor

also reference [Flutter BottomNavigationBar Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927929/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-colors?rq=1)

code snippet

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            fixedColor: Colors.white,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icon(Icons.access_time, color: Colors.white),
                title: Text('Edifice', ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                title: Text('Adresses', ),
              ),
            ],

          )
```

Test result of Story App UI with BottomNavigationBar

[image]

Comment: My Godness, it was so easy. I haven't figured out these properties. I still learning flutter, i am such a noob. Thanks a lot. you saved my day !!